# Using Redis just for blocking and call back functionality or springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, redis

This is what I am trying to do and wondering if I should use Redis or there is a springboot equivalent that I could use for what I am trying to achieve.

I am trying to send a receipt of a transaction to a merchant. I need to attach digital signature for that transaction in the receipt. **That would be a call to a separate API to get the digital signature which could return me a 200 or 404 not found**. At this point there could be a scenario that digital signature is not available, in that case, I need to wait for a specific amount of time for the signature to become available and if it times out then need to send the receipt without the digital signature.

I am using Java and SpringBoot.

What would be the best way to implement something like this. I read that redis has a timeout, callback functionality which can be leveraged for this.

1. Is there any springboot equivalent to do something like this or redis is a good choice for this.
2. If redis would be a good choice for this, how can I leverage redis just for this purpose. I have access to a container running redis and I can configure my application to access this redis. However I have no clue of how I can go about using redis for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

According to me you don't need Redis for this requirement.

Redis is a cache used for quicker access to certain data.
for eg :- select queries from DB.

For your requirement I can think of an approach:-

Since it's an API call you can handle response-timeouts by using Retry Logic wherein you keep retrying 2-3 times if you get 404 in a interval of 5min(Configurable as per your needs) and even after 10 min if there is no data you just send the receipt without digital signature.

Eg :- In Spring Boot we have RestTemplate to invoke any GET/POST API and has Retry Logic functions.

Comment: Here is what I learned from my lead today. He is thinking of leveraging redis as queue. So we can push this task in the queue , so retry till timeout happens to get the digitial signature or just try ones after timeout. But dont hold up the caller on that. Push this into redis queue, retrun a 200 OK back and then process one after another element from redis queue. He is preferring redis because it has an ability to take the peek at the top element in the queue, without actually dequening it. So you can peek at the top element, and only dequeue and process it only when its ready.

Comment: This approach would be asynchronous. If it fits your requirement then ok